# Java: enrich xml with elements through regex string parsing

Tags: java, regex, xml, dom, xpath

I have a complex task to transform docx document to JATS XML. For now I have grab everything that it is possible from docx with xslt. And the next step is parsing xml file and update it by changing some xml strings (text in nodes) to xml elements. I have not found this information in somewhat similar questions on this forum. My input xml looks like this:

```
<article dtd-version="3.0" article-type="other">
  <body>
    <sec>
      <title>mySuperTitle</title>
        <p>
          This is some scientific stuff [1]. Here is more complicated info. This text is even more bizarre [2,3].
        </p>
        <p>
           Einstein formulas [4]. String theory [5,6]. Really don`t know what to write here[7,8]. 
        </p>
      </sec>
      <sec>
        <title>AnotherBoringTitle</title>
        <p>
          Another one section and obviously here is even more citations [9,10,11]
        </p>
     </sec>
   </body>
</article>
```

Ideally, I want to replace all [citations], which are simple numbers in [], to xml elements. For example:

```
<article dtd-version="3.0" article-type="other">
  <body>
    <sec>
      <title>mySuperTitle</title>
        <p>
          This is some scientific stuff [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="bib1">1</xref>]. Here is more complicated info. This text is even more bizarre [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="bib2">2</xref>,<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="bib3">3</xref>].
        </p>
        <p>
          Einstein formulas [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid ="bib4">4</xref>]. String theory [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid ="bib5">5</xref>,<xref ref-type="bibr" rid ="bib6">6</xref>]. Really don`t know what to write here [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid ="bib7">7</xref>,<xref ref-type="bibr" rid ="bib8">8</xref>]. 
        </p>
     </sec>
     <sec>
        <title>AnotherBoringTitle</title>
        <p>
          Another one section and obviously here is even more citations [<xref ref-type="bibr" rid ="bib9">9</xref>,<xref ref-type="bibr" rid ="bib10">10</xref>,<xref ref-type="bibr" rid ="bib11">11</xref>]
        </p>
     </sec>
   </body>
</article>
```

I don`t have much experience in Java, but already tried to use DOM, Xpath and regex for this task. The problem is when I parse the document and get the node, I must get it from DOM, transform to string, replace chars in string to number, transform to element and make the output. I find it problematic to transform this string to element (this requires to create new documentBuilder, or how it calls) and replace the proper element in DOM for ouput a new xml.
Is here an easy solution? Or I must write many lines of code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works using DOM and regexex:

I assume you know how to find the right `Text` node.

You then need to:

```
//get the split point:
int prevSplitOffset = 0;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]").matcher(textNode.getData());
while (m.find()) {
  // get the text and split it:
  Text number = textNode.splitText(m.start(1) - prevSplitOffset);
  textNode = number.splitText(m.group(1).length());

  // Replace the number with a new DOM node:
  Element xref = document.createElement("xref");
  xref.setAttribute("rid", "bib" + m.group(1));
  xref.setAttribute("ref-type", "bibr");
  number.getParentNode().replaceChild(xref, number);
  xref.appendChild(number);
  prevSplitOffset = m.end(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am using the xpath to find needed nodes. I will check this code tomorrow, but I assume this it what I am looking for.

Comment: Be sure to adjust the variable names to your environment ;-)

Comment: Could you please change number.getParentNode().replaceChild(number, xref); to number.getParentNode().replaceChild(xref, number); And the 2nd problem is that it finds only first citation in one text_node. If there is 2nd - throws an error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: The index or size is negative, or greater than the allowed value

Comment: I fixed it. After splitting for the first time, you need to adjust the offset.