# Java: split node with splitText() method

Tags: java, regex, xml, xpath

My aim is to make XML input, replace some text in node to XML DOM element and produce XML output. My XML input and expected output can be found [here, in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41730030/java-enrich-xml-with-elements-through-regex-string-parsing/41730229).

Here is my java code:

```
private static void textTransformCitations(Document document) 
{       
    XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "/article/body/sec/p/text()";
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        Node textNode = nodeList.item(i);
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+)\\]").matcher(textNode.getNodeValue());
        while (m.find()) 
        {
          Text number = textNode.splitText(m.start(1));
          textNode = number.splitText(m.group(1).length());
          Element xref = document.createElement("xref");
          xref.setAttribute("rid", "bib" + m.group(1));
          xref.setAttribute("ref-type", "bibr");
          number.getParentNode().replaceChild(number, xref);
          xref.appendChild(number);
        }
    }
}   // Added by edit!
```

Obviously the problem is that `splitText()` can be used only for Text interface:

> textNode.splitText

which `textNode` variable is not. But I have explicitly stated to retrieve text from nodes with XPath.

What can I do to make this code working?
How can I use the `splitText` method in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the statement `Node textNode = nodeList.item(i);` to `Text textNode = (Text)nodelist.item(i);`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it works :) There is some more problems with this code, but that`s another story.